# Gradcam not able to visualize ResNet Layers' Features

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, transfer-learning

I am working on something that require to visualize the layers of the pretrained model. I am able to visualize the layers for inceptionV3 and other models but failed for ResNet50 model using GradCam. I can only see a complete blue mask on the image. The accuracy for ResNet50 model is quite low also.

Below is what I see
[image]

And below is how I create the model

```
 preprocess_input = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input 
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
    
    x = preprocess_input(inputs)
    
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(include_top=False, input_tensor=x, weights="imagenet",input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
        
    flat1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.layers[-1].output)
    flat2 = Dropout(0.2)(flat1)
    class1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(flat2)
    output = Dense(30, activation='softmax')(class1)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=output)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Were you able to resolve this?  thanks!